# CKErrorNotAuthenticated on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, cloudkit

I try to fetch the userRecordID. In the simulator it is working, but not on my iPad. On the iPad I get a CKErrorDomain" - code: 9 which means CKErrorNotAuthenticated even if I logged in to iCloud before in the iPad-Settings. So what am I missing? Do I have to register something programmatically or to switch sthg on in the iPad settings? Thanks

```
if(self.usrRecordID == nil) {
    CKContainer.defaultContainer().fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler({ userRecordID, error in
        self.stopActivityIndicator()
        if error != nil {
            self.showMsg("Error...", vc: vc)
            return
        } else {
            self.usrRecordID = userRecordID //USRID
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What message do you get when you call: CKContainer.defaultContainer().accountStatusWithCompletionHandler({status, error in NSLog("Account status = \(status.hashValue) (0=CouldNotDetermine/1=Available/2=Restricted/3=NoAccount)")})

Comment: With iCloud Drive enabled it is working now. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I will put it into an answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before executing the method:

```
CKContainer.defaultContainer().fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler({ userRecordID, error in
    ...
}
```

You should call the method:

```
CKContainer.defaultContainer().accountStatusWithCompletionHandler({status, error in
    NSLog("Account status = (status.hashValue) (0=CouldNotDetermine/1=Available/2=Restricted/3=NoAccount)")
})
```

The response should be 1, If it's 3, then the you have to login into iCloud

Comment: Thank you! I already logged in into iCloud before but without iCloud Drive enabled in the settings and this seems to be required.